# Issue with update of objects in AWS S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

While building an AWS website for one of my client I am having issues with the eventual consistency of S3 Bucket while updating an object.

In one of the feature that we have developed the user can update his profile picture and we are saving the profile picture in the S3 bucket and saving the public URL of it in the DB for later retrieval.

Now for new Objects it is working fine but for updates it is taking time(~ 5-10 mins) for the update to happen. I have explored the internet and could not find a solution to this. Some people suggested to use a versioning like v1/filename and v2/filename and with update take the data from the latest version directory but this is too impractical.

Can any one please suggest me what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enable versioning in the bucket and use the versioning features to get the latest - rather than altering the path.  s3 will handle the number of copies.  See

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=263531 for a discussion of this feature and consistency